# pfsense - route OpenVPN roadwarrior over IPSec to secondary office

Tags: openvpn, ipsec, pfsense

Having some trouble connecting clients from one office to the other.

```
  (10.1.1.0/24)             (192.168.5.0/24)
   Office ONE  <--- IPSec ---> Office TWO
        ^
        |
        v
  Road Warrior 1 (OpenVPN client)
    (10.1.2.2)
```

**I've added an extra P2:**
VPN / IPsec / Tunnels / Edit Phase 2
tunnel  10.1.2.0/24 192.168.5.0/24  ESP

**And I've also added to OpenVPN custom Options:**
VPN / OpenVPN / Servers / Edit
push "route 192.168.5.0 255.255.255.0";

But still `Road Warrior 1` can only ping servers in the `10.1.1.0/24` subnet.

Any idea what I'm missing or what I've done wrong? Both pfsense boxes.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone Googling here with the same issue.

**1) You must configure IPSec P2 with the following (reverse for Office B)**

```
Mode    Local Subnet   Remote Subnet
tunnel  10.1.1.0/24    192.168.5.0/24  (to connect office A to office B)
tunnel  10.1.2.0/24    192.168.5.0/24  (to connect OpenVPN from A to office B)
tunnel  10.1.1.0/24    192.168.2.0/24  (to connect OpenVPN from B to office A)
```

**2) You must open firewall** (Firewall -> IPSec -> Rules)

```
Protocol    Source          Port    Destination Port    Gateway
IPv4 *      192.168.5.0/24  *       *           *       *
IPv4 *      192.168.2.0/24  *       *           *       *
```

**3) Restart the IPSec service!**

I failed to do this and it cost me 1h trying to dig what was wrong.